# App42 cloud service (baas) - bulk upload possible?

Tags: app42

Is this possible? Or do I have to upload one document after another? Which needs very long if you want to upload thousends of documents... As with downloading, bulking together 100 documents would be quite nice...

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Through dashboard its not possible however you can write a custom script in which you can pic the files & make a chunk of 50 or 100 to upload your files on App42 server using App42 [File Upload API](http://api.shephertz.com/app42-docs/file-upload-service/).

Naresh

Comment: You mean, writing a function that uploads 100 files one after another? I can't find anything better than that... And I would like to upload json documents... But not one after another but an array of objects or so...

Comment: Because uploading one after another takes quite a lot of time... Although the data is not much....

Comment: Uploading a JSON array is not a recommended way to do because if you upload the JSON array, you will not able to find a specific key in that array. Also when you fetch the document, it will always download the whole data which also impact on the network bandwidth.

Comment: I know... But it would be technically possible to send an array to the server (just for fast transmittment) and the response could be an array as well... I want SEPERATE documents on the server, I just want to send a bunch of documents at once... I think, App42 does not support this for uploads. Btw, in my case, I am creating 1500 documents, this needs about 30 min or so (just estimated...)

Comment: You can import your data from AppHQ Management Console through .json file. Have a look at this blog post & let me know if it helps.http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/10/17/migrating-data-from-other-baas-providers/#more-9084

Comment: To insert the json array, you need to create a key and place the value as JSON array in document. For example: You have JSON array of something like [{"name":"prom"},{"score":50},{"id":85}], you can place this type of array in storage as key = "UserArray" and value =[{"name":"prom"},{"score":50},{"id":85}]. and your JSON document will look like this: {"UserArray" :[{"name":"prom"},{"score":50},{"id":85}]}

Comment: Actually, I was aware of this... But I need it as part of my app... Would be nice, if it would be possible to use such an array through the api and not only through the dashboard...